# Can we use Aspose.Words (for .Net) version 13.5.0.0 in .Net microservice?

Tags: .net, aspose.words

We have one asp.net webservice using Aspose.Words version 13.5.0.0 for mail merge functionality.

We are planning to convert this web service into microservice for better maintainability and scalability.

So, I want to know Aspose.Words version 13.5.0.0 is compatible to use with microservice or not or Do I need to upgrade to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use it in microservices. But you should note that Aspose.Words for .NET 13.5.0 provides only .NET Framework versions. So if you would like to pack your microservice into a Docker Image – you should use it in [.NET Framework Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/).

The latest version of Aspose.Words also provides .NET Standard 2.0 version, so you can use it in .NET Core Docker images, which are much smaller than .NET Framework. Please follow the link to learn [how to use Aspose.Words in Docker](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/How+to+Run+Aspose.Words+in+Docker).

And finally, if you use Java version of Aspose.Words, you can surely use it in Docker containers with Java installed. 
Hope I answered your question.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.